# sitemap.xml only for bots

Tags: sitemap, bots

is it possible to show my web Page's sitemap.xml only to bots , and if someone want to see it and click for example ; http://www.mywebpage/sitemap.xml receive a not permitted warning message , for some reson I should do it , Has anybody a idee

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really any difference between a bot and a person other than the `User-Agent` header (and then only if you're lucky). That said, it should be straightforward to return a 403 or a surrogate page based on agent.

What web server are you using?

Comment: what control do you have over configs? e.g. can you install rewrite rules?

Comment: I can not , is it not possible via .htaccess

Comment: maybe if you link to your hosting provider's docs, we could suggest something concrete.